# Is there any .c source file available to convert TAI time to UTC?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, utc, date-conversion, datetime-conversion, real-time-clock

I am trying to implement BLE mesh Time model. The time data received from the mesh is in TAI format and i need to use local RTC to keep track of this time. For this, I have to convert the **TAI time** from mesh to **UTC** locally so that my node can keep track of time using RTC. I'm looking for a generic **C source file** that would do this before jumping into implementation. Can anyone suggest if it's already there?

Comment: According to wikipedia, TAI is exactly 37 seconds ahead of UTC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time#:~:text=It%20is%20the%20principal%20realisation,37%20seconds%20ahead%20of%20UTC.

Comment: https://github.com/chmike/posix_tai_time_converter this can convert TAI to posix time format. Maybe it helps you

Comment: "According to wikipedia, TAI is exactly 37 seconds ahead of UTC" |


Currently and only since 2017-01-01, the date the last leap second was introduced into UTC. The next leap second (none is scheduled for the next possible date, 2022-07-01) will change that.

Answer (score 1):

IAU SOFA library (https://www.iausofa.org/current_C.html#Downloads) has `iauUtctai()` and `iauTaiutc()` subroutines for conversion between UTC and TAI (and many other timescales too). And it is written in ANSI C.